# Start SSH Agent from golang, docker, and alpine

Tags: go, ssh

I have a go program that I need to add a ssh key to. The SSH agent is not running when the container starts so I have been trying to figure out how to get it to start.

No matter what I try get an error that ssh-add cannot connect to the agent

```
  os.Mkdir("/root/.ssh", 0700)
  privateKeyPath := "/root/.ssh/id_rsa"
  err := ioutil.WriteFile(privateKeyPath, []byte(request.Source.GitPrivateKey), 0600)
  if err != nil {
    log.Panic(err)
  }

  err = exec.Command("ssh-agent").Run()
  if err != nil {
    log.Panic(err)
  }
  err = exec.Command("ssh-add", privateKeyPath).Run()
  if err != nil {
    log.Panic(err)
  }
```

Comment: What is the error you are seeing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ssh-add` (and `ssh` and others) need to know how to contact `ssh-agent`.

This is done through the `SSH_AGENT_SOCK` environment variable.

When you run `ssh-agent`, it will print something like the following which is usually evaluated:

```
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-OLGZ7hANaDNH/agent.31224; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
SSH_AGENT_PID=31225; export SSH_AGENT_PID;
echo Agent pid 31225;
```

You have two options here:

#### Parse the value of `SSH_AUTH_SOCK`:

Then set it as an environment variable (eg: using [os.Setenv](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Setenv)) for the call to `ssh-add` and your further calls to `ssh`.

#### or Make your own temporary file name:

And specify it as a custom bind address using `ssh-agent -a /path/to/my/custom/unix-socket`, then set that as the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` environment variable.

Comment: Any updates on this one? I have tried the above to no avail.